# Application Administration Console Architecture

Tags: java, architecture, console, admin

Good time folks,

we have a standalone highly-loaded java application (actually, a cluster of such applications) that processes trade orders.
It's entry point is a JMS queue where it takes massages from. Each message is then verified/validated, enriched, persisted and sent to one of several subsribers.

Today our customers came to us with a requirement of implementing an 'administration' console for the application. This console should provide several operational features like changing processing flags, invoking internal features and processes on demand (rather than waiting the next scheduler iteration), ...

As far as we want to reorganize our application's architecture following the well-known best practices (of course, we are not the first people in the world, who need to develop such the console :) ) we started searching for ones, and ... found nothing well-described, which is rather confusing.

Of course, the JMX technology could be used here, but, unfortunately, an operations team (and customers) want something like Windows prompt/Unix bash which could be used with DSL commands...

Could somebody please assist us pointing to any resources that could help dealing with the task. Actually, does not matter whther it is java or any other programming language. I believe that this kind of questions is language-agnostic.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possibly better suited for [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: the first thing that came to my mind is develop a REST API within the application to modify its internal flags, and then develop the shell commands that send calls to the REST API

Comment: You could create a DSL for this, as you mentioned, and a simple console which can be used to run its commands. ANTLR would get you there.

Comment: Thanks, guys! So the idea is to open a dedicated port for an 'operational' web service to provide required administration manipulations, and implement a separate simple console application that will communicate with the web service transforming DSL commands to service requests, right?